# Multiple threads increasing int

Tags: c#, multithreading, int

I have a problem when multiple threads try to increase int. Here's my code:

```
private int _StoreIndex;
private readonly List<Store> _Stores = new List<Store>();

public void TestThreads()
{
    _StoreIndex = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                while (_StoreIndex < _Stores.Count - 1)
                {
                    _Stores[Interlocked.Increment(ref _StoreIndex)].CollectData();
                }
            });
        thread.Start();
    }
}
```

I would expect that int gets increased by one each time the thread executes this code. However, it does not. I have also tried using lock (new object()), but this doesn't work as well. The problem is that not all the stores collect data because (when debugging), _StoreIndex goes like 0, 1, 1, 3, 4, 5, for example. The second object in the list is obviously skipped.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You do realize that `while (_StoreIndex < _Stores.Count - 1)` will skip the last store, don't you?  More commonly, it would be `while (_StoreIndex < _Stores.Count)` or less commonly `while (_StoreIndex <= _Stores.Count - 1)`

Comment: `lock(new object())` will never lock the code.  You want to lock on a instance of a single object, not a new one each time.

Comment: Remember, that some threads may check the condition in while and then work on incremented value - you definitely need to lock all accesses to _StoreIndex in these threads with one lock. Maybe you would like to use `Parallel.ForEach()`?

Comment: @phoog If it were `while (_StoreIndex < _Stores.Count)`, in the last iteration `_StoreIndex` would be `_Stores.Count - 1`. Then it would get increased by one and became `_Stores.Count`. Referencing `_Stores[_Stores.Count]` would throw an exception.

Comment: Multiple threads access `List<T>` which is not thread safe

Comment: Biggest problem is that this code will blow past StoreCount-1.  That's probably where the -1 came from.

Comment: You have a race condition. Your code is starting 20 threads, with each thread running the while loop. Please explain what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Witchunter so you are incrementing at the beginning of the loop, not the end?  If that is the case, then you must be skipping the first element of your collection.

Comment: @Witchunter oh, yes, of course.  In that case, though, you are skipping the *first* store, since List is zero-based, and Interlocked.Increment will return 1 on the first iteration.  You need `for (int i = 0; i < _Stores.Count; i++)` and you need to initialize `_StoreIndex` to -1.

Comment: To all of you referencing the indexing issues: I'm sure your intentions were good, but my problem was not in indexing and this was not part of the question at all. I could easily sort out indexing issues (which were clearly present) had I been able to make threads process the stores taking them in a consecutive order and without skipping some of them. Parallel.For is the solution and will surely make things much less complicated. Thank you all for your comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case I would use the TPL to avoid all of these problems with manual thread creation and indexes in the first place:

```
Parallel.ForEach(_Stores, (store) => store.CollectData());
```

Comment: There are problems in question in accessing `_Stores` and `_StoresIndex` in parallel(**RACE CONDITIONS**). What does this answer solve?

Comment: @L.B: This code tries to bypass incrementing the index in each thread by transforming the processing of each individual element of the array into a separate task and feeding it to a Thread Pool. It is a much cleaner rewriting of the original problem and it is correct.

Comment: @BrokenGlass, Yes you are correct. Just edit your answer for undo downvote

Comment: @BrokenGlass I was not aware of For and ForEach in Parallel namespace. Thank you for your answer, although For will better suit my needs.

Answer (score 3):

I think it should be corrected to:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
{
    int index = 0;
    while ((index = Interlocked.Increment(ref _StoreIndex)) < _Stores.Count - 1)
    {
         _Stores[index].CollectData();
    }
});
```

Now index is local, so there is no interference, while _StoreIndex is only used atomically in a single place.

Comment: This way I would not need threading at all, I could easily run this code from the main thread with the same effect. What I really need is multiple threads doing their part of the work, each one collecting data for a different store.

Comment: @Witchunter: This is just your code corrected to make it atomic.

Comment: If your initial code was parallel, this is parallel too. It's exactly the same thing.

Comment: In my code, I was trying to distribute data collecting between multiple threads. I was trying to use single shared indexing, each time incremented, so that the next thread takes the next object from a shared list. In your code, a single thread has its own index and processes all objects from a list.

Comment: No it's not like that: Each thread has its index, but that index is obtained by atomic increment of the shared _StoreIndex. See the condition of the while. Feel free to implement it and see that it's parallel.

Comment: Ah, I see now. Sorry for not seeing the obvious. Upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an atomic operation:

```
_Stores[Interlocked.Increment(ref _StoreIndex)].CollectData();
```

Increment is atomic, but this line contains more code than a simple increment. You may need to sort out your indeces first, then use thread safe collection to hold your stores, like ConcurrentBag and perhaps consider TPL library and classes like `Task` and `Parallel` to perform the workload.